# Unexpected flickering mouse and constant clicking

Tags: mouse

I have installed Elementary recently and all works wonderful. I only fight with this issue.

The cursor or mouse arrow is clicking constantly for a while. Then it mostly stops for a minute and comes again. Of course it is impossible to select a window or write a text. This problem does not appear right after system start. It often comes after a while or when I login again. Wherever I leave the mouse arrow it starts clicking.

I unplugged the mouse (apple mouse) and keyboard and it keeps on clicking. I investigated across the web, but could not find a solution. Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the reason was my optical mouse. I used no mouse pad and somehow it started flickering after a while. I started using a mouse pad and it woks now just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after some search I found 3 solution I implement in my laptop. Cursor still "clicking/blinking" but less than before. Here is my changes to lessen this behavior:

I.

First try to add in `/etc/environment` file:

```
CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling
CLUTTER_VBLANK=True
```

and logout and login again.

II.

If this does not help try from console:

```
settings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false && gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active true
```

III.

If the problem still occurs and you have Intel video cards you could also create file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and add in there:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
   Option "TearFree" "True"
EndSection
```

After that you need to restart your computer.

In my case I'm not sure what helped most, because I implemented those changes one by one, and cursor blinking less now. Still most annoying this is on Scrivener program running from wine. When I write on Firefox or mail there is nearly no blinking. My Elementary is running on VirtualBox and my laptop has Intel graphic card.

I hope this can help you.